# Postman is not returning value after post in postman?

Tags: php, service, postman

This is test.php file:

```
<?php

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (isset($postdata)) {
    $request = json_decode($postdata, true);
    echo $request->pid;
}

?>
```

And I am trying to send pid using POST method from postman but I am getting error like:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\test.php on line 5

Comment: what does var_dump($request) print? I guess $postdata is empty and unable to read properly.

Comment: postdata is coming but when I decode it. It is getting NULL

Comment: remove the true param from json_Decode and then var_dump it.Lets check whether we do really have pid as a key

Comment: The second argument (`true`) will decode the json object as an array instead of an object, so try: `echo $request['pid'];` instead or remove the second argument to `json_decode()`.

Comment: Yes thats right. It decodes it as an array and not as an object. @MagnusEriksson is rgt

Comment: it is printing when I remove decode and just typing $_POST['pid']

Comment: Are you posting the data as a json string in the body using postman or are you sending it as key/value-pairs (since )? If you're sending it as key/value-pairs, then you won't get it as a json string but should use `$_POST['pid']` to access the value. In the top of your file, do a `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_POST);` and check which is populated with what. Add the result to your question as well.

Comment: getting result like this : 

string(5) "pid=4"
array(1) {
  ["pid"]=>
  string(1) "4"
}

Thanks for quick reply all of you.. :)

Comment: One more question if I want access pid then How can I access ? based on above result?

Comment: `$_POST['pid']`

Comment: Ok thank you got the point..:)